# Discord.js Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When i try executing this code i get an error. "Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read".

Line 18 : Column 19

```
const { Client, Intents, Collection } = require('discord.js')

const config = require('./config.json')

const fs = require('fs')

const bot = new Client({ intents: [ Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES ] })

bot.commands = new Collection()

var cmdFiles = fs.readFileSync('./cmd').filter(f => f.endsWith(".js"))

for(const f in cmdFiles) {
    const cmd = require(`./commands/${f}`)

    bot.commands.set(cmd.help.name, cmd)
}

bot.once("ready", () => {
    console.log('Bot is ready!')
})

bot.on("messageCreate", async message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;

    var prefix = config.prefix

    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    var array = message.content.split(" ");

    var command = array[0];

    const data = bot.commands.get(command.slice(prefix.length))

    if(!data) return;

    var args = array.slice(1)

    try {
        await data.run(bot, message, args)
    } catch(e) {
        await message.channel.send(e)
        await console.log(e)
    }
})

bot.login(config.token)
```

Yes all config things are defined.
I've tried searching for this error but got nothing that i need.

What i want to do is load every file from the directory 'cmd' in a array list and run a command if it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
var cmdFiles = fs.readFileSync('./cmd').filter(f => f.endsWith(".js"));
```

to this:

```
var cmdFiles = fs.readdirSync('./cmd').filter(f => f.endsWith(".js"));
```

As your question states, `./cmd` is a directory and you can't list the files in a directory with `fs.readFileSync()`.  You would use `fs.readdirSync()` to do that.

`fs.readFileSync()` tries to open the directory as a file and read its contents.  Since it's not a file, you get the EISDIR error.

Comment: if i do that i get an error "Error: Cannot find module './commands/0'" 21:17

Comment: @Youri_Miner - That is apparently the next error you encounter with this code and has nothing to do with your original question.  This change fixes the error you asked about in your question.  You need to debug the next error and then ask a new question if you get stuck on it.

Comment: @Youri_Miner - FYI, `fs.readdirSync()` returns ONLY the filenames.  They are not combined with the path.  So, if you want to actually do something with those files and they aren't in the current working directory, you will have to combine the filename with the path before trying to use it.

Comment: Isn't there a way to load the files from a directory? Or is fs.readdirSync() the only option?

Comment: @Youri_Miner `fs.readdirSync` is at least the best option... and as for the new error you get, you can ask a new question